# Either use Loader's source or sourceComponent depending on <javascript expression>

Tags: javascript, qml, qt5

I have a hard time using a Loader that decides on `source` or `sourceComponent` depending on some javascript expression. I tried this:

```
    Component {
        id: emptyComponent

        // for debugging, I would usually use Item {≠
        Rectangle {anchors.fill:parent; color: "red"}
    }

    Component {
        id: handStrengthColumnDelegate

        Loader {
            source: styleData.value !== undefined ? 'qrc:/resources/myDelegate.qml' : ''
            sourceComponent: styleData.value === undefined ? emptyComponent : undefined
        }
    }
```

with the idea that, used as delegate for a table column, I would like to use my custom delegate in the case that data is given for the respective row and an empty component in case that there is no data (this is a different kind of row, namely a category).

However, it seems that setting `sourceComponent` to `undefined` results in `source` being ignored... What I want is an *either/or* relationship.

I could move `emptyComponent` to a distinct file or I could use a *Loader* for `myDelegate.qml` and only use `sourceComponent` but is there any other way without such workaround?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the [Qt documentation for the Loader QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#source-prop) about the `source` property:

> To unload the currently loaded object, set this property to an empty string, or set sourceComponent to undefined. Setting source to a new URL will also cause the item created by the previous URL to be unloaded.

This is why setting `sourceComponent` to `undefined` causes `source` to be ignored - it simply unloads the component again.

Since your `emptyComponent` is empty (apart from the rectangle for debugging purposes), instead of setting the source depending on the value of `styleData.value` you can set the `active` property instead.

The resulting QML looks like this:

```
Component {
    id: handStrengthColumnDelegate

    Loader {
        source: 'qrc:/resources/myDelegate.qml'
        active: styleData.value !== undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Although not displayed, `active` still leads to an evaluation of the model delegate. I still get errors in the QML console because it tries to access properties of `styleData` which is undefined.
I do not get errors if I choose to have either `myDelegate.qml` or `EmptyDelegate.qml` depending on `styleData`...

Comment: @IceFire How about conditionally setting `source` to the empty string when `styleData.value === undefined`? Then you don't even need to use the `active` property.